# Why my animation speed increases every time I press the button?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Here is a link: https://jsfiddle.net/danbogdan/Ltsxnude/6/
I am trying to make some animation that has 'blades', but every time I press the button the speed increases on that specific animation, or the next one!
I would like to increase or decrease the speed based on the option values! So after the user input the number of propellers, he can choose how many blades a propeller can have 2-8, and the speed. Now, every time I click the button in increases the speed of the current animation, and the next one if I choose a 3 blades propeller.

```js
function propellersNumber() {
  var number = document.getElementById('noOfPropellers').value;
  var container = document.getElementById('container');
  while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
    container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Propeller " + (i + 1) + " number of blades: "));
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.id = "propeller" + i;
    input.type = "number";
    input.defaultValue = 2;
    input.min = 2;
    input.name = "propeller" + i;
    container.appendChild(input);
    container.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
    container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Propeller " + (i + 1) + " speed: "));
    var select = document.createElement('select');
    select.id = "innerSelect" + i;
    var option;
    var inputdata = "slow||medium||fast";
    inputdata.split('||').forEach(function(item) {
      option = document.createElement('option');
      option.value = option.textContent = item;
      select.appendChild(option);
    })
    container.appendChild(select);
    container.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
  }
}



function switchBetween() {
  var numberPropellers = document.getElementById('noOfPropellers').value;
  var el = document.getElementById('propeller0');
  var result = el.value;
  var speed = document.getElementById('innerSelect0');
  var speedResult = speed.options[speed.selectedIndex].value;
  if (result == 2) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("propellerOne");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var angle = 0;
    if (speedResult == "slow") {
      angle = 2;
    } else if (speedResult == "medium") {
      angle = 6;
    } else if (speedResult == 'fast') {
      angle = 10;
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    function animate() {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      ctx.lineWidth = 1;
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
      ctx.lineTo(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.lineWidth = 1;
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(canvas.width, 0);
      ctx.lineTo(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
      ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 180 * angle);
      ctx.translate(-canvas.width / 2, -canvas.height / 2)

    }
  } else if (result == 3) {
    // 3 blades 

  }
```

```html
<pre>
    <h2>Input number of propellers</h2>
    <input type="number" id="noOfPropellers" name="propeller" min="0" value="0" id="propeller">
    <button onclick="propellersNumber()">Add</button>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <button onclick="switchBetween()">Switch</button>
    <div class="container">
        <canvas class="propeller" id="propellerOne" height="120px"></canvas>
    </div>
</pre>
```

Comment: Side note, your `canvas` tag isn't closed

Comment: As this is a very "large" code and hard to debug theoretically: could you provide a running example on common js playgrounds?

Comment: You are calling `requestAnimationFrame(animate)`, and then that function `animate` does the same thing again - that's what is effectively creating a "loop" of `animate` executions here. But then the next time you click your button, you are creating a _second_ such loop, the first one never got "cancelled" anywhere.

Comment: With the "classic" `setInterval`, you would get an interval identifier back, that can be used with `clearInterval` to stop the whole thing again. But here, you have just a function that calls "itself" again - indirectly, via `requestAnimationFrame`. So you would either need a way to _stop_ the function from doing that at a certain point; or see to it that you create only one such loop to begin with, that keeps on running, and have only the parameters change.